# Keras One Hot Encoding Memory Management - best Possible way out

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, chatbot, one-hot-encoding

I know this problem has been answered in different ways in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058780/python-one-hot-encoding-for-huge-data). But I am not able to figure out and fit in my code and need help. I am using the [cornell movie corpus](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/memorability_files/cornell_movie_quotes_corpus.zip) as my dataset. Trying to train a LSTM model for chatbot is the final expectation. But I am stuck with initial one hot encoding and is getting out of memory. Note the VM I am training is 86GB memory but still having issues.In nmt_special_utils_mod.py the one hot encoding is going beyond allocated memory and I am not able to pass the stage. Any alternative way to do these line will be helpful without loosing the functionality

```
Xoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), X)))
Yoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(machine_vocab)), Y)))
```

All codes as below to make the question clear

**import_corpus_mod.py** - 
Change 1: updated less frequent word removal

```
def data_load():
TrainDataSetPath = 'D:\\Script\\Python\\NLP\\chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt\\ChatBot\\'

####initializing libraries####
#import numpy as np
#import tensorflow as tf
import re
#import time

########### Data Pre-processing Part 1##########

def clean_text(text):
    '''The function will clean known texts and make it more meaningful'''
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am", text)
    text = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"it's", "it is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"let's", "let us", text)
    text = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "what is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"how's", "how is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"howz", "how is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", text)
    text = re.sub(r"don't", "do not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"can't", "cannot", text)
    text = re.sub(r"wouldn't", "would not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"wasn't", "was not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"haven't", "have not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\s+"," ",text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>+=~|{}.?,]", "", text)
    #####Add more below this line######
    #####Add more above this line######
    return text

lines = open(TrainDataSetPath+'movie_lines.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read().split('\n')
conversations = open(TrainDataSetPath+'movie_conversations_short.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read().split('\n')

#Create dictionary which maps each line with its corresponding ID

id2line = {}
for line in lines:
    _line = line.split(' +++$+++ ')
    if len(_line) == 5:
        id2line[_line[0]] = _line[4]

#Create list of all conversation
conversations_ids = []
for conversation in conversations[:-1]:             #the last line in conversation is blank hence -1
    #Split then pick last part[-1] which is conversation. Then Removing square bracket by [1:-1] and then replacing quotes and space
    _conversation = conversation.split(' +++$+++ ')[-1][1:-1].replace("'","").replace(" ","")
    # Append to form a list of list separating by comma
    conversations_ids.append(_conversation.split(","))

#Separating the question and answer - assuming the first is the question second is the answer in a conversation
questions = []
answers = []
threshold = 5   #If more than 15 counts of words

for conversation in conversations_ids:
    for i in range(len(conversation)-1):
        questions.append(id2line[conversation[i]])
        answers.append(id2line[conversation[i+1]])

# Cleaning all questions
clean_questions = []
for question in questions:
    clean_questions.append(clean_text(question))



# Cleaning all answers
clean_answers = []
for answer in answers:
    clean_answers.append(clean_text(answer))

# Creating a dictionary that maps each word to its number of occurrence
word2count = {}
for question in clean_questions:
    for word in question.split():
        if word not in word2count:
            word2count[word] = 1
        else:
            word2count[word] += 1
for answer in clean_answers:
    for word in answer.split():
        if word not in word2count:
            word2count[word] = 1
        else:
            word2count[word] += 1

#Create dictionary of words which has more occurrence than threshold

for k in list(word2count):
    if word2count[k] < threshold:
        del word2count[k]

cleanest_questions, cleanest_answers, keys_list = [], [], list(word2count.keys())


for answers in clean_answers:
    ans = []
    for word in answers.split():
        if word in keys_list:
            ans.append(word)
        else:
            ans.append('<unk>')
    cleanest_answers.append(' '.join(ans))

for question in clean_questions:
    ques = []
    for word in question.split():
        if word in keys_list:
            ques.append(word)
        else:
            ques.append('<unk>')
    cleanest_questions.append(' '.join(ques))

return cleanest_questions, cleanest_answers
```

**nmt_data_load_asmain_words.py** 
Change 1 : update less frequent word removal

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from import_corpus_mod import data_load

def load_dataset(clean_questions, clean_answers):
    """
        Loads a dataset with m examples and vocabularies
        :m: the number of examples to generate
    """
    human_vocab = set()
    machine_vocab = set()
    dataset = []
    lines = len(clean_questions)

    for i in tqdm(range(lines)):
        hu, mc = clean_questions[i], clean_answers[i]
        if hu is not None:
            dataset.append((hu, mc))
            human_vocab.update(set(hu.split()))
            machine_vocab.update(set(mc.split()))

    human = dict(zip(sorted(human_vocab) + ['<pad>'], 
                     list(range(len(human_vocab) + 1))))
    #human = dict(zip(sorted(human_vocab) + ['<pad>'], 
                     #list(range(len(human_vocab) + 1))))
    #human = dict(zip(sorted(human_vocab), 
                     #list(range(len(human_vocab)))))
    machine = dict(zip(sorted(machine_vocab) + ['<pad>'], 
                     list(range(len(machine_vocab) + 1))))
    #machine = dict(zip(sorted(machine_vocab) + ['<pad>'], 
                     #list(range(len(machine_vocab) + 1))))
    inv_machine = {v:k for k,v in machine.items()}
    inv_human = {p:q for q,p in human.items()}

    return dataset, human, machine, inv_machine, inv_human




clean_questions, clean_answers = data_load()
dataset, human_vocab, machine_vocab, inv_machine_vocab, inv_human_vocab = load_dataset(clean_questions, clean_answers)
```

**nmt_special_utils_mod.py**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

# Initiate a list to store integer version of sentences
X_into_int = []
Y_into_int = []

def preprocess_data(dataset, human_vocab, machine_vocab, Tx, Ty):

    X, Y = zip(*dataset)

    X = np.asarray([string_to_int(i, Tx, human_vocab) for i in X])

    Y = [string_to_int(t, Ty, machine_vocab) for t in Y]
    Xoh, Yoh = [], []
    Xoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), X)))
    Yoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(machine_vocab)), Y)))

    return X, np.array(Y), Xoh, Yoh

def string_to_int(line, length, vocab):
    #print("hello- inside function")
    """
    Converts all strings in the vocabulary into a list of integers representing the positions of the
    input string's characters in the "vocab"

    Arguments:
    string -- input string, e.g. 'Hello how are you'
    length -- the number of time steps you'd like, determines if the output will be padded or cut
    vocab -- vocabulary, dictionary used to index every character of your "string"

    Returns:
    rep -- list of integers (or '<unk>') (size = length) representing the position of the string's character in the vocabulary
    """
    '''    
    #make lower to standardize
    for string in listofstring:
        string = string.lower()
        string = string.replace(',','')

        if len(string) > length:
            string = string[:length]

        rep = list(map(lambda x: vocab.get(x, '<unk>'), string))

        if len(string) < length:
            rep += [vocab['<pad>']] * (length - len(string))

    #print (rep)
    return rep
    '''
    newlist = []
    if len(line.split()) > length:
        line = line.split()
        for i in range(length):
            newlist.append(line[i])
        line = ' '.join(newlist)

    else:
        line = line + ' <pad>' * (length - len(line.split()))
        #print(line)
        #print("hello- inside padded")
    #words_into_int = []
    ints = []
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in vocab:
            ints.append(vocab['<unk>'])
        else:
            ints.append(vocab[word])
            #print("hello- inside append if loop")
    #words_into_int.append(ints)
    #words_into_int = ",".join(x for x in words_into_int)
    return ints        

def int_to_string(ints, inv_vocab):
    """
    Output a machine readable list of characters based on a list of indexes in the machine's vocabulary

    Arguments:
    ints -- list of integers representing indexes in the machine's vocabulary
    inv_vocab -- dictionary mapping machine readable indexes to machine readable characters 

    Returns:
    l -- list of characters corresponding to the indexes of ints thanks to the inv_vocab mapping
    """

    l = [inv_vocab[i] for i in ints]
    return l


EXAMPLES = ['3 May 1979', '5 Apr 09', '20th February 2016', 'Wed 10 Jul 2007']

def softmax(x, axis=1):
    """Softmax activation function.
    # Arguments
        x : Tensor.
        axis: Integer, axis along which the softmax normalization is applied.
    # Returns
        Tensor, output of softmax transformation.
    # Raises
        ValueError: In case `dim(x) == 1`.
    """
    ndim = K.ndim(x)
    if ndim == 2:
        return K.softmax(x)
    elif ndim > 2:
        e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
        s = K.sum(e, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
        return e / s
    else:
        raise ValueError('Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is 1D')


def plot_attention_map(model, input_vocabulary, inv_output_vocabulary, text, n_s = 128, num = 6, Tx = 30, Ty = 10):
    """
    Plot the attention map.

    """
    attention_map = np.zeros((10, 30))
    Ty, Tx = attention_map.shape

    s0 = np.zeros((1, n_s))
    c0 = np.zeros((1, n_s))
    layer = model.layers[num]

    encoded = np.array(string_to_int(text, Tx, input_vocabulary)).reshape((1, 30))
    encoded = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(input_vocabulary)), encoded)))

    f = K.function(model.inputs, [layer.get_output_at(t) for t in range(Ty)])
    r = f([encoded, s0, c0])

    for t in range(Ty):
        for t_prime in range(Tx):
            attention_map[t][t_prime] = r[t][0,t_prime,0]

    # Normalize attention map
#     row_max = attention_map.max(axis=1)
#     attention_map = attention_map / row_max[:, None]

    prediction = model.predict([encoded, s0, c0])

    predicted_text = []
    for i in range(len(prediction)):
        predicted_text.append(int(np.argmax(prediction[i], axis=1)))

    predicted_text = list(predicted_text)
    predicted_text = int_to_string(predicted_text, inv_output_vocabulary)
    text_ = list(text)

    # get the lengths of the string
    input_length = len(text)
    output_length = Ty

    # Plot the attention_map
    plt.clf()
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8.5))
    ax = f.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    # add image
    i = ax.imshow(attention_map, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Blues')

    # add colorbar
    cbaxes = f.add_axes([0.2, 0, 0.6, 0.03])
    cbar = f.colorbar(i, cax=cbaxes, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.ax.set_xlabel('Alpha value (Probability output of the "softmax")', labelpad=2)

    # add labels
    ax.set_yticks(range(output_length))
    ax.set_yticklabels(predicted_text[:output_length])

    ax.set_xticks(range(input_length))
    ax.set_xticklabels(text_[:input_length], rotation=45)

    ax.set_xlabel('Input Sequence')
    ax.set_ylabel('Output Sequence')

    # add grid and legend
    ax.grid()

    #f.show()

    return attention_map
```

**nmt_code_mod.py** the main code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr 10 16:31:44 2018

@author: Anirban
"""

from keras.layers import Bidirectional, Concatenate, Dot, Input, LSTM
from keras.layers import RepeatVector, Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from nmt_data_load_asmain_words import load_dataset
from import_corpus_mod import data_load
from nmt_special_utils_mod import *

epochs = 50


clean_questions, clean_answers = data_load()
dataset, human_vocab, machine_vocab, inv_machine_vocab, inv_human_vocab = load_dataset(clean_questions, clean_answers)

m = len(clean_questions)
Tx = 8
Ty = 8
X, Y, Xoh, Yoh = preprocess_data(dataset, human_vocab, machine_vocab, Tx, Ty)

print("X.shape:", X.shape)
print("Y.shape:", Y.shape)
print("Xoh.shape:", Xoh.shape)
print("Yoh.shape:", Yoh.shape)

# Defined shared layers as global variables
repeator = RepeatVector(Tx)
concatenator = Concatenate(axis=-1)
densor1 = Dense(20, activation = "tanh")
densor2 = Dense(1, activation = "relu")
activator = Activation(softmax, name='attention_weights') # We are using a custom softmax(axis = 1) loaded from nmt_special_utils
dotor = Dot(axes = 1)

def one_step_attention(a, s_prev):
    """ 
    Performs one step of attention: Outputs a context vector computed as a dot product of the attention weights 
    "alphas" and the hidden states "a" of the Bi-LSTM. 

    Arguments: 
    a -- hidden state output of the Bi-LSTM, numpy-array of shape (m, Tx, 2*n_a) 
    s_prev -- previous hidden state of the (post-attention) LSTM, numpy-array of shape (m, n_s) 

    Returns: 
    context -- context vector, input of the next (post-attetion) LSTM cell 
    """  

    ### START CODE HERE ###  
    # Use repeator to repeat s_prev to be of shape (m, Tx, n_s) so that you can concatenate it with all hidden states "a" (≈ 1 line)
    s_prev = repeator(s_prev)
    # Use concatenator to concatenate a and s_prev on the last axis (≈ 1 line)
    concat = concatenator([a,s_prev]) 
    # Use densor1 to propagate concat through a small fully-connected neural network to compute the "intermediate energies" variable e. (≈1 lines)  
    e = densor1(concat)  
    # Use densor2 to propagate e through a small fully-connected neural network to compute the "energies" variable energies. (≈1 lines)  
    energies = densor2(e)  
    # Use "activator" on "energies" to compute the attention weights "alphas" (≈ 1 line)  
    alphas = activator(energies)  
    # Use dotor together with "alphas" and "a" to compute the context vector to be given to the next (post-attention) LSTM-cell (≈ 1 line)  
    context = dotor([alphas,a])  
    ### END CODE HERE ###  

    return context 

n_a = 32
n_s = 64
post_activation_LSTM_cell = LSTM(n_s, return_state = True)
output_layer = Dense(len(machine_vocab), activation=softmax)

def model(Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s, human_vocab_size, machine_vocab_size):
    """
    Arguments:
    Tx -- length of the input sequence
    Ty -- length of the output sequence
    n_a -- hidden state size of the Bi-LSTM
    n_s -- hidden state size of the post-attention LSTM
    human_vocab_size -- size of the python dictionary "human_vocab"
    machine_vocab_size -- size of the python dictionary "machine_vocab"

    Returns:
    model -- Keras model instance
    """

    # Define the inputs of your model with a shape (Tx,)
    # Define s0 and c0, initial hidden state for the decoder LSTM of shape (n_s,)
    X = Input(shape=(Tx, human_vocab_size))
    s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
    c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
    s = s0
    c = c0

    # Initialize empty list of outputs
    outputs = []

    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Step 1: Define your pre-attention Bi-LSTM. Remember to use return_sequences=True. (≈ 1 line)
    a = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_a, return_sequences=True),input_shape=(m, Tx, n_a*2))(X)

    # Step 2: Iterate for Ty steps
    for t in range(Ty):

        # Step 2.A: Perform one step of the attention mechanism to get back the context vector at step t (≈ 1 line)
        context = one_step_attention(a, s)

        # Step 2.B: Apply the post-attention LSTM cell to the "context" vector.
        # Don't forget to pass: initial_state = [hidden state, cell state] (≈ 1 line)
        s, _, c = post_activation_LSTM_cell(context,initial_state = [s, c])

        # Step 2.C: Apply Dense layer to the hidden state output of the post-attention LSTM (≈ 1 line)
        out = output_layer(s)

        # Step 2.D: Append "out" to the "outputs" list (≈ 1 line)
        outputs.append(out)

    # Step 3: Create model instance taking three inputs and returning the list of outputs. (≈ 1 line)
    model = Model(inputs=[X,s0,c0],outputs=outputs)

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return model

model = model(Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s, len(human_vocab), len(machine_vocab))
opt = Adam(lr=0.05, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,decay=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

s0 = np.zeros((m, n_s))
c0 = np.zeros((m, n_s))
outputs = list(Yoh.swapaxes(0,1))

model.fit([Xoh, s0, c0], outputs, epochs=epochs, batch_size=5)

EXAMPLES = ['can we make this quick  roxanne korrine and andrew barrett are having an incredibly horrendous public break up on the quad  again'
            ,'the thing is cameron  i am at the mercy of a particularly hideous breed of loser  my sister  i cannot date until she does'
            ,'Hello how are you']
#EXAMPLES = ['13 May 1979', 'Tue 11 Jul 2007','Saturday May 9 2018', 'March 3 2001','March 3rd 2001', '1 March 2001','23 May 2017']
for example in EXAMPLES:

    source = np.asarray([string_to_int(example, Tx, human_vocab)])
    #need a try block here to prevent errors if vocab is small and example has characters not in the vocab
    source = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), source)))   #.swapaxes(0,1)
    prediction = model.predict([source, s0, c0])
    prediction = np.argmax(prediction, axis = -1)
    output = [inv_machine_vocab[int(i)] for i in prediction]
    pads = output.count('<pad>')
    output = output[0:(len(output)-pads)]
    print("source:", example)
    print("output:", ' '.join(output))
```

Note: The code is as is code of very famous research paper in 2016 which coverts any date time to computer understandable date time. I was trying to re-use that for our Chatbot - Seq2Seq with Attention Model (bi-directional). The code is working - just that the movie corpus if loaded in 1000 conversation it works. When you load the full corpus it fails due to memory overload

**EDIT**

Thank You for collaboration efforts on this problem - Really appreciate the trouble you are taking to go through the code and trying to find out the best possible solution for this. As you instructed I have updated the **import_corpus_mod.py** to incorporate the threshold = 5 and at the very beginning converting the least frequent words less than 5 to < unk > without space. This change forced another small change in **nmt_data_load_asmain_words.py** to remove the addition of < unk > there.

Now based on the other point and the code shared by you - I hashed out the below lines in **nmt_special_utils_mod.py**

```
#Xoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), X)))
#Yoh = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(machine_vocab)), Y)))
```

And straight away change the input based on your guidance?

```
Xi = Input(shape=(Tx,))
X  = Embedding( human_vocab_size, 100, embeddings_initializer='uniform', input_length=Tx , trainable=True )(Xi)
s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
s = s0
c = c0
```

Got lot of errors

```
runfile('D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot/nmt_code_mod.py', wdir='D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot')
Reloaded modules: nmt_data_load_asmain_words, import_corpus_mod, nmt_special_utils_mod
100%|██████████| 384/384 [00:00<00:00, 24615.06it/s]
100%|██████████| 384/384 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
X.shape: (384, 8)
Y.shape: (384, 8)
D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py:1592: UserWarning: Model inputs must come from a Keras Input layer, they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "model_2" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer embedding_1.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: embedding_1/Gather:0
  str(x.name))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-44-addb6f9e6bc1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot/nmt_code_mod.py', wdir='D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot')

  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot/nmt_code_mod.py", line 138, in <module>
    model = model(Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s, len(human_vocab), len(machine_vocab))

  File "D:/Script/Python/NLP/chatbotSeq2SeqWithAtt/ChatBot/nmt_code_mod.py", line 132, in model
    model = Model(inputs=[X,s0,c0],outputs=outputs)

  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 1652, in __init__
    layer.__class__.__name__))

TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: [<tf.Tensor 'embedding_1/Gather:0' shape=(?, 8, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 's0_1:0' shape=(?, 64) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'c0_1:0' shape=(?, 64) dtype=float32>]. Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `Embedding`
```

So reverting back the code here for nmt_code_mod.py and nmt_special_utils_mod.py

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using one-hot encodings and a dense matrix.
If you have a vocabulary of 100.000 words a 100.000 x 100.000 consumes more than 70Gb of RAM.

You can try using sparse a sparse matrix. But I guess that changes the rest of your code. you may take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609892/keras-sparse-matrix-issue).

You could use is word embeddings representations, which are compact, memory friendly and used by all the state of the art NLP systems.

In any case, one think you must do with your model is to handle embedding inputs using the proper [embedding layer](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/).
This layer stores the embedding matrix once, and then you can build your training samples giving only one integer that represents the index of the word in the vocabulary.

If you want one hot encodings, you can build an embedding layer with a NxN identity matrix using a [Keras initializer](https://keras.io/initializers/#identity). Where N is the size of the vocabulary. Then your can pass as input the indexes of the words as integers. This will increase the size of your model, but it will reduce the size of your batches.

If you want word2vec embeddings, you can load an embedding matrix with a NxV dimensions. Where N is the size of the vocabulary and V is the dimension of the embeddings. You will notice that V is normally set to 100 or 200 dimensions, which is much smaller than N. Saving you a lot of memory.

**EDIT**: to clarify the usage of embeddings in your case:

You do:

```
X = Input(shape=(Tx, human_vocab_size))
s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
s = s0
c = c0
```

Instead you can do one-hot-encoding this way:

```
Xi = Input(shape=(Tx,))
X  = Embedding( human_vocab_size, human_vocab_size, embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.Identity, input_length=Tx )(Xi)
s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
s = s0
c = c0
```

By doing this, you can build your training samples using only the word indexes and not the one hot vectors. This will make you save some space in the training samples, but your model will be larger in size.
If it is still too large, you won't have the choice but using dense embeddings. To do so, you can do the following:

```
Xi = Input(shape=(Tx,))
X  = Embedding( human_vocab_size, 100, embeddings_initializer='uniform', input_length=Tx , trainable=True )(Xi)
s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
s = s0
c = c0
```

This initializes embeddings randomly with a compact representation (dimension 100 instead of human_vocab_size). This would save you a lot of memory.

Finally you could reduce the size of your vocabulary by putting everything in lowercase or replacing rare words (that appear only once or twice in the corpus) with an special token "RARE"

Comment: You are right. Its a VM with pooling enabled - I can see it is going upto 120GB Memory usage before crashing. Using Sparse matrix will change everything. Also accuracy might fall? By word Embedding you mean like Glove or gensim ? Isn't that more memory hungry? Ah yes I introduced <UNK> for that just not introduced the code yet - not sure how well it will go?

Comment: Your problem is the following, the dimension of your vectors is too large. Therefore when you load your dataset it does not fit in memory. So you can load smaller batches as nuric says (being careful of knowing the full vocabulary size). Or you can use an embedding layer from Keras.  I update my response with details on how to use this embedding layer

Comment: I tried my level best to get this sorted - but after scratching my head for 2 days I give up. Looks like it is too difficult and beyond my capability - i do not have anyone locally to discuss as well. I am adding all codes in the post - not sure how I can proceed there after

Comment: I have edited the post by incorporating the RARE functionality replaced with unk. For the model piece i tried to use your recommendation - but I guess Xoh and Yoh are used in model.fit statement                                                    
outputs = list(Yoh.swapaxes(0,1))
model.fit([Xoh, s0, c0], outputs, epochs=epochs, batch_size=5)

Comment: I am thinking of using glove vector encoding - but not sure if I can get around it well. I don't think we have much options left here

Comment: Did you test the embedding layer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not one-hot encoding but rather storing the entire dataset in memory. The wise choice is to a generator, or a [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) which will allow you to load and encode the data on the fly. This is commonly done for large image datasets for example.

I would recommend to perform all your pre-processing and save input, output pairs without encoding as a csv file, then you can create a generator that lazily loads and encodes:

```
class MySequence(Sequence):
  def __init__(self, data, batch_size):
    self.data_file = data
    self.batch_size = batch_size

  def __len__(self):
     return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

  def __getitem__(self, batch_id):
    # Get corresponding batch data...
    # one-hot encode
    return X, Y
```

Note the generators (or Sequence[i]) returns a single batch.

Comment: Thank You - I have never used keras Sequence. Will give it a try. Just wondering isn't this a very common problem with seq2seq training? Isn't there an option to do kind of reinforcement learning? Where I learn in batches and update the weights etc?

Comment: It is a common thing, and that is why generators return a single batch, train and then repeat.

Comment: I have updated the whole code here. But can't get around to fit in the memory.